# Laravel 5.3. Dispatching job has odd error

Tags: notifications, jobs, laravel-5.3

Title says it all and here is code

Controller:

```
public function declineReservation($id){
        $reservation=Reservation::where('id',$id)->with('user','apartment')->get()->first();
        $this->dispatch(new SendMails($reservation));
        $reservation->delete();
        return redirect('reservations')->with('status', 'reservation declined');
}
```

Job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Notifications\ReservationApproved;
use App\Notifications\ReservationDeclined;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendMails implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $reservation;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($reservation)
    {
        $this->reservation=$reservation;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $user=$this->reservation->user;
        if($this->reservation->status==1){
            $user->notify(new ReservationApproved($this->reservation));
        }
        else{
            $user->notify(new ReservationDeclined($this->reservation));
        }
    }
}
```

And now comes the funny part. Reservations in declineReservation method have status that is equal to 0, so in job handle they go to else block but mail is not being sent, unless i remove

```
$reservation->delete();
```

from declineReservation method.

This is my first question ever on stack so i hope you all will be eager to help with this fickle problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking i realized since job is triggered a bit later after syncronus delete it cant get deleted model so instead of deleting it i set my model so it is able to be "soft deleted", then after job is executed(sending mail) i delete record from database.

Model:

just add this

```
use SoftDeletes;
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

dont forget to import SoftDeletes or use full path.

Migration:

add this to schema builder

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

Controller:

```
public function declineReservation($id){
     $reservation=Reservation::withTrashed()->where('id',$id)-with('user','apartment')->get()->first();
     $this->dispatch(new SendMails($id));
     $reservation->delete();
     return redirect('reservations')->with('status', 'reservation declined');
}
```

Job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Notifications\ReservationApproved;
use App\Notifications\ReservationDeclined;
use App\Reservation;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendMails implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

protected $param;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($param)
{
    $this->param=$param;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    if(is_object($this->param)){
        $user=$this->param->user;
        $user->notify(new ReservationApproved($this->param));
    }
    else{
        $reservation=Reservation::withTrashed()->where('id',$this->param)->get()->first();
        $reservation->user->notify(new ReservationDeclined($reservation));
        $reservation->forceDelete();
        }
    }
}
```

In Job handle i check if param is object since when reservation is approved i pass model to constructor and on decline i pass model id so i can load him with withTrashed() method. After that just "force delete" the model.

For more information about soft deleting refer to: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#soft-deleting